# Find a maximum element in this list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python Task for online course on Udacity although I put the right code for the task it still gives me that is wrong answer. Can any one tell me why?? You are required to complete the function maximum(no_list).  the function is expected to return the maximum numbers in that list.

Example:

> input : [5,20,12,6] 
> output: 20

```
no_list = [1,2,3,4]
  def maximum(no_list): 
    #complete the function to return the highest number in the list

  print(maximum(no_list))
```

Comment: You most probably need to RETURN the maxno - not print it ....

Comment: print != return. Instead `return maxnum`

Comment: Note that the course assignment may not allow to use `max`. Also, better use different name for variable, don't reuse the name of the function, it's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Simply return the maxnum instead of printing it

**Change print To return**

**For Example**

```
no_list = [1,2,3,4]

def maximum(no_list):

  maxnum= max(no_list)

  return maxnum
```